# erroneous pipeline: no element "facedetect"

Tags: opencv, gstreamer, face-detection

I am trying to detect face using (Gstreamer open-cv) plugin, using following pipeline.

Face detection from image

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=/home/talview22/Pictures/face.png ! decodebin ! ffmpegcolorspace ! facedetect ! ffmpegcolorspace ! ximagesink
```

face detection on live feed

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! 'video/x-raw-rgb,width=640,height=480' ! ffmpegcolorspace ! faceblur face-width=40 face-height=40 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! xvimagesink
```

getting following error,

> WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "facedetect"

facedetect plugin already installed, I checked.

```
talview22@talview22-System-Product-Name:/var/www/html/backboneapp$ gst-inspect-1.0 facedetect
Factory Details:
  Rank                     none (0)
  Long-name                facedetect
  Klass                    Filter/Effect/Video
  Description              Performs face detection on videos and images, providing detected positions via bus messages
  Author                   Michael Sheldon <mike@mikeasoft.com>
```

How can I resolve?

Comment: It's strange that you're not getting any errors for `ffmpegcolorspace` as it was removed in 1.0 (becoming `videoconvert`, see http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/chapter-porting-1.0.html). In a simple pipeline like `gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! ffmpegcolorspace ! autovideosink` I get `no element "ffmpegcolorspace"`, for example. Are you sure you don't have symbolic links pointing to 0.10 binaries or something?

Comment: Thank you for replay, I got it. Without ffmpegcolorspace Its working with 1.0 following command is executed "gst-launch-1.0 autovideosrc ! video/x-raw,width=320,height=240 ! videoconvert ! facedetect  ! videoconvert ! autovideosink"